# How to draw in picturebox so drawing doesn't disappear?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls, picturebox

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593290/how-to-draw-on-control-so-drawing-doesnt-disappear)

but I don't understand how to solve my problem though. When I move, minimize or cover the form's window, draws disappear.

There is part of my code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.Green, 2);
long i; //this value changes each tick and is set by another method

picturebox1.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(pen, 0 + i, 0, 0 + i, 10); 
picturebox1.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(pen2, 0 + ((i*2)/1.2), 0, 0 + ((i*2)/1.2), 50); }
```

I need the code is in `timer1_Tick()` method because it must draws at each tick.
Am I using the `OnPaint()` method and its override? If yes, how to do it in my scenario?

Comment: Draw on a bitmap, and in OnPaint, draw that bitmap.

Comment: A wanted to give you an answer, but the question is closed...

Comment: really? I didn't closed anything. Sorry mr @HenkHolterman if I started a new topic about this argument but some other help is appreciated.

Comment: First of all, don't create Graphics object, draw only in Paint method and use the Graphics from event args. If you want to repaint PictureBox, call Invalidate() in timer1_Tick() method

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman What Paint method are you talking about?

Comment: PictureBox has an event called Paint. You can handle this and that's where you can draw, e.g:
pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;

Comment: @ŁukaszRejman thk you it sounds like what I need. I'll study on it.